# Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus I to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus I to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{1}{x} {\displaystyle \int}_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2}dt$

---

My professor sets $F(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2}dt$

We also find that,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2}dt = F'(0)$$

And thus,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2}dt = f(0) = \sqrt{9 + 0^2}$$

---

But where does the $\frac{1}{x}$ go? It seems as if it was ignored. What if we had $x^4$ instead of just $x$? I hope this isn't something terribly trivial that I'm somehow missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Definition of the derivative.

Comment: L'hospital rule is an alternative way to see the same result

Comment: @ThePortakal But a less intuitive way to use FTC IMO and not the way the OP's prof showed it (which is what OP is asking about)

Comment: The $x$ in denominator is part of definition of derivative and hence the given limit is $F'(0)$ which by FTC is equal to $f(0)=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{9+t^2} \, dt$, then
$$F'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x} 
\left(\int_0^x\sqrt{9+t^2}\,dt-0\right).$$